# How do I append the text from input to a newly created div using java script?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to use document.getElementById("ques").value; to get the input from the user to append to a new div that will be displayed in , This method has not worked however and I am not sure where to proceed from here.

What can I do to append the question to the div and then display the div?

```
    </section>
    <div id="questiondiv">
        <form action= "javascript:myFunction()" >
            <input type="text" name="question" id="ques" value="" placeholder="Ask a Question"> <br> <br>
            <input type="text" name="elaboration" id="elab" value="" placeholder="Elaborate"> <br> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var node = document.getElementById("ques").value;
            div.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById ("placeholder")
            element.appendChild(para);

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(node)` does this return what you expect?

Comment: use `div.innerHTML = node` instead of `div.appendChild(node)`. and at the end you try to append an element `para`. i assume you want to append your `div`.

Comment: Martin E Thank you for the help your solution has worked out perfectly!